# Relation between two database Hasmany

Tags: mysql, laravel, mongodb

I want to create a relation between MYSQL > MongoDB in Laravel.

For MongoDB I use the Jenssegers libary.

Solution, I have several items inside mongoDB all with a parent id, and my parent is saved inside mysql. I do a get on my parent with a "with" on my items.

The problem is only that my items are from Mongo and not from Mysql, so I used the following:

```
/**
 * @return HasManyJens
 */
public function items(): HasManyJens
{
    return HasManyJens::setConnection('Items')->hasMany(Item::class, 'item_id', 'id');
}
```

But the following error appear.

```
Call to undefined relationship [items] on model [App\Models\Parent]
```

Comment: What you're referring to is called 'Polygot Persistence' and you need to consider whether it's worth the added complexity and lack of integrity checks/consistency? If you're data is structured and has natural relationships, just keep it together.

Comment: Understand, is there any solution to fix this without writing a hard query?

Comment: Unless you have the option of using a single data store rather than pairing MySQL and MongoDB together, I think you might have to write some custom conversion code to convert the `HasManyJens` type to a standard Laravel `HasMany` (and vice-versa). Not something I have experience with.

Comment: @Peppermintology saldy but i completly understand. thanks!